# Background-Image of Stack Exchange Newsletter Advertisement does not fit

Tags: bug, design, advertising, sidebar

Not a big thing, but the Background-Image (https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/stackexchangemeta/img//newsletter-ad.png) of the Stack Exchange Newsletter Advertisement does not fit in the sidebar and is cut off on the right side.

I´m using latest Chrome without zooming.

**Example:**

[image: Cut Off]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed. At least the add is now displayed correctly and the border on the right side is visible.